# How to get details about Vmmem process activity?

Tags: windows

Vmmem is using 30% CPU whereas docker desktop is not started and WSL is not activated
how to understand the cause of the activity ?

Comment: Look at Hyper-V Manager to see what VM causes the usage. Then use some process manager inside of the corresponding VM (e.g. `top`).

Comment: HyperV manager Showed DockerDestop was started despite I didn't configured it to start automatically. The Docker-Desktop Wale command Icon wasn't even available. A bug, following an update of either Docker-Desktop or windows is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Hyper-V Manager showed the DockerDesktopVM  was running.
I deactivated DockerDesktopVM in the Hyper-V Manager then right clicked/parameters/administration|management(fr: Gestion)/Automated start Action/ then
Choosed the "do nothing option" at physical computer start